# Calling a click event or JQuery function from the code behind VB.NET

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a JQuery (v1.8) which handles the code after clicking a hyperlink. I would like to call that click or do anything else (as the clicking of the link would) to enforce the JQuery to run from the code behind. Any ideas?

JQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function (){    
    jQuery('#lnkShowModule').toggle( 
        function (){ 
            jQuery(this).html('Hide the Module'); 
            jQuery('.hide-element').toggle(); 
        }, 
        function (){ 
            jQuery(this).html('Show the Hidden Module'); 
            jQuery('.hide-element').toggle(); 
        }
    );
});
```

and this is my link in the ascx control:

```
<a id="lnkShowModule" href="#"> show the hidden module</a>
```

any ideas?

Comment: what are you trying to do? and why you need it on codebehind since you know which "a" you have to click on to class that jquery function?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaElDin I want to perform the actions from the javascript after another event even if the user doesn't click on the link.

Answer (score 2):

add the javascript code inside a function and you can add the following code whereever you want to call the javascript function

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Page.GetType(), "ShowHide", "ShowHideDiv();", true);
```

**#UPDATE 1**

```
function ShowHideDiv(){
$(document).ready(function (){    
    $('#lnkShowModule').toggle( 
        function (){ 
            $(this).html('Hide the Module'); 
            $('.hide-element').toggle(); 
        }, 
        function (){ 
            $(this).html('Show the Hidden Module'); 
            $('.hide-element').toggle(); 
        }
    );
});
}
```

also you have to change the " a "

```
<a id="lnkShowModule" href="#" onclick="ShowHideDiv();"> show the hidden module</a>
```

Comment: @AhmedAlaaElDin That's exactly what I have in my code, but I think I don't put the right function name. I don't know much about scripting. So based on my code, what is the "Anyname" and "FUNCTIONANME()" that I should use?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaElDin Thanks for that. Well, my document is kind of messed up now. The module which I wanted to show/hide appears always, it doesn't get hidden and it's misplaced...

Comment: aha i see,but it works that calls the function from code behind successfully?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaElDin Unfortunately, not

Comment: did you try to add an alert(''); on top of " $(document).ready(function (){   " to check if it gets called?

Comment: @AhmedAlaaElDin I did it like this $(document).ready(function (){    alert('');
    $('#lnkShowModule').toggle( and yes it gets called both by the text link and by the code behind. But the module it's still misplaced and the show/hide don't work

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36176/discussion-between-ahmed-alaa-el-din-and-nectarines)

Answer (score 1):

If you're already posting back (as you noted in your question that you're wanting to do this from the code-behind), then you can simply set the visibility of the object in question from the code-behind as well.

If your intention is to hide a div, you can turn it into an asp:Panel (MyPanel) (which outputs a div). Then you can simply call:

```
MyPanel.Visible = False; ' or True
```

to set the visibility. No javascript/jquery required.

Comment: No, I'm hiding something else, a module, not the link.